# page parts not showing in the backend, refinerycms

Tags: refinerycms

Suddenly my page parts defined in for the home page view template are not showing, the content appear fine in the front end but when I try to edit the content, it looks empty and the custom page parts I created are not showing.

I'm not getting any type of error so I don't know where to look.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

JJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure that pages.rb, under initializers/refinery allows for configuring new page parts (config.new_page_parts = true).

Second, try creating a new database with a different name, changing your database.yml file to connect to the new database (presumably under development), and running migrations. Or create a new database and restore it from a last known good version. If your content is visible in both the front end and the back end after changing databases, all will be well again.

I had a similar problem recently, where Refinerycms would serve content in page views but not in admin layouts. It happened after I reverted my application code by cloning from a shared repository. Not sure why but restoring an earlier version of the database fixed it.

Comment: I found out that when testing and making early deployments you might create two home pages on the database. Once I figure that, I just deleted the page id duplication and issue solved.